# reselect object from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I using reselect and I have some problem about select state from my store.

My redux store look like:

```
store = {
  boxs: {
    space: 'large',
    view: 'card',
    options: {
      option01: { id: '01', name: 'Option1', value: true },
      option02: { id: '02', name: 'Option2', value: false },
      option03: { id: '02', name: 'Option3', value: false },
    },
  },
};
```

Here is my `selector.js`

```
const getSpace = createSelector(
  (state) => state.boxs.space,
  (space) => space
);

const getSpaceAndView = createSelector(
  (state) => state.boxs,
  (boxs) => ({
    space: boxs.space,
    view: boxs.view,
  })
);

const getOptions = createSelector(
  (state) => state.boxs,
  (boxs) => ({ ...boxs.options })
);

// I use this but when options change value, Component3 not re-render, why ???
/*const getPreferences = createSelector(
  (state) => state.boxs,
  (boxs) => boxs.options
);*/
```

My reducer

```
reducers = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case 'CHANGE_OPTIONS':
      const { key, val } = action; // key = 'option01' | 'option02' | 'option03', value = true || false
      const newState = { ...state };
      newState.boxs.options[key].value = val;
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I have 3 components. Component1 use `state.boxs.space`. Component2 use `state.boxs.view` and `state.boxs.space`. Component3 use `state.boxs.options`. When Component3 change `state.boxs.options` value (dispatch action CHANGE_OPTIONS in my reducer). Component2 and Component1 will re-render. How to stop re-render ? Thank for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the component code for the three components and their parent components so we may better see why component 1 & 2 are rerendering when the options state is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use this but when options change value, Component3 not re-render,
> why ???
>
> ```
> /*const getPreferences = createSelector(
>   (state) => state.boxs,
>   (boxs) => boxs.options
> );*/
> ```

The reducer should be a pure function. You look to be mutating state objects. You should shallow copy ***all*** the data you'll be updating.

```
reducers = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case 'CHANGE_OPTIONS':
      const { key, val } = action; // key = 'option01' | 'option02' | 'option03', value = true || false

      return {
        ...state,
        boxs: {
          ...state.boxs,
          options: {
            ...state.boxs.options,
            [key]: {
              ...state.boxs.options[key],
              value: val,
            },
          },
        },
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

A small improvement to be more DRY and utilize memoization is to create an initial input selector to select your `state.boxs` object to be used as input to the other selectors.

```
const boxsSelector = state => state.boxs;

const getSpace = createSelector(
  [boxsSelector],
  boxs => boxs.space,
);

const getSpaceAndView = createSelector(
  [boxsSelector],
  boxs => ({
    space: boxs.space,
    view: boxs.view,
  })
);

const getOptions = createSelector(
  [boxsSelector],
  boxs => boxs.options,
);
```